# Extend TextBox control and change part of default style

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, extending-classes

I want to create a class library (dll file) of the WPF TextBox with extended functionality. But i want to change one part of the TextBox's default style (IsMouseOver property trigger).

I created a new WPF user control library project, deleted the generated .XAML and .cs files from it, and added a new class file. Then i derived from the TextBox class, but i don't know how to access the style XAML.

I can't figure out how this supposed to be done..

Inside my project i currently have only this .cs file, and no .XAML file:

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private string customProperty;
        public string CustomProperty
        {
            get { return customProperty; }
            set { customProperty = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, if you just take the TextBox, and on the designer right click and chose edit template -> edit copy, and then modify what you need to modify inside the template?.

Comment: yes, but i have other functionality in the code behind that i want to include in the custom text box. i didn't include it here for simplicity. and i want a reusable control with the combined code behind and the style changes functionality. anyhow, you know if it can be done like this in a dll library like i wanted?

Comment: Sure it can, all you have to do is to, add new UserControl, and name it CustomTextBox (if this is what you want) and then replace the Tag UserControl with TextBox, and from this point you can use this TextBox just like the user control, but you will still have your code behind that you can access. I find this much easier than custom control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<TextBox x:Class="CustomControls.MyFolder.CustomTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</TextBox>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want to do in your xaml (edit template, apply style etc), and you'll have access to it from code behind.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Comment: Well, unfortunately i tried this, and the xaml doesn't effect the control when importing the dll to another project.

Comment: @moonlander Can you edit your question to show what have you done?, we use this approach all the time and it works.

Comment: It's alright, I forgot to add the InitializeComponent();